# jq display different fields of a json file

Tags: shell, jq

I want to get different values from a json file with jq but i can't get values which are in a different level.

Here is the json i have :

```
{
  "id": 132,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "project": "TEST-Sylvain",
  "executionType": "user",
  "user": "sthirard",
  "date-started": {
    "unixtime": 1560946609000,
    "date": "2019-06-19T12:16:49Z"
  },
  "date-ended": {
    "unixtime": 1560946613000,
    "date": "2019-06-19T12:16:53Z"
  },
  "job": {
    "id": "7a8dfbb0-a4b1-4309-8b76-f04cd0f03af2",
    "averageDuration": 3060,
    "name": "TEST_chainage_job",
    "group": "DEPLOYMENT",
    "project": "TEST-Sylvain",
    "description": "JOb d'installation  ",
  },
  "description": "hostname [... 4 steps]",
  "argstring": null,
  "successfulNodes": [
    "acde",
    "bfgh"
  ]
}
```

I can get id / user but i can't get the date field.

```
jq '.executions[0] | "\(.id) \(.user)"' response.json
```

I tried

```
jq '.executions[0] | .date-started.date' response.json
```

but it doesn't work

Can you help me with that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Your json invalid: `"description": "JOb d'installation  ",` leading comma here, and it doesn't have `executions`. Probably it must looks like this: https://gist.github.com/cn007b/b7daa7dde19310ad3283629e1e6f81b0

Comment: Yeah i forgot to correct it here i have hidden ip fields, thanks for your answer btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to do something like this:

```
jq '.executions[0] | "\(.id) \(.user) \(."date-started".date)"' response.json
```

Comment: jq '.executions[0] | "\(.id) \(.user) \(."date-started".date)"' response.json
jq: error (at response.json:1): Cannot index array with string "date"

Comment: json provided in your question bit invalid, please try to use this one: https://gist.github.com/cn007b/b7daa7dde19310ad3283629e1e6f81b0

Comment: Ok thanks - it works with that json ! But when i validate my json it's ok - gonna investigate why such a result.

Comment: @Lamz You may try to use http://json.parser.online.fr/ to validate your json, maybe it'll help...

Comment: Yes it was just a piece of a big json that has more than 1000 lines, it was just an extract and i use this website which confirms that my json is OK

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the given JSON in the obvious way, the following invocation of jq produces the results shown below:

```
$ jq -r '[.id, .user, ."date-started".date] | join(" ")' input.json
132 sthirard 2019-06-19T12:16:49Z
```

You might like to consider using `@csv` or `@tsv` instead of using `join`; and you might have to prepend `.executions[0] |` to the above pipeline.